# Different evaluation accuracy when loading BERT from checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-estimator

For some reason, I get wildly different loss and acc when I evaluate my BERT test set right after training vs. when I load from a saved checkpoint. I thought it might have been my adaptation of BERT, so I tried modifying the run_classifier.py script as little as possible to fit my use case, and I still am seeing this problem.

The only reason I can think of is that the model isn't loading correctly, but I don't know how to fix it. I believe I'm loading how originally intended. For the init_checkpoint parameter, I pass path/to/classifier/model.ckpt-{last_step}. There are three model files (meta, index, data) but there are also the checkpoint, events, and graph files. Do I need to be doing something with those other three files as well? I'm used to using keras, and this pure tensorflow saving/loading process seems unnecessarily convoluted to me.

Thank you in advance for any help/insight regarding BERT or pure tf saving/loading! If you're unfamiliar with BERT, here's the github link: [BERT GitHub](https://github.com/google-research/bert)

Comment: Hope the following url will be helpful for you:https://github.com/bigboNed3/bert_serving/tree/44d33920da6888cf91cb72e6c7b27c7b0c7d8815.  Also please share the command you are using to run the evaluation

Comment: @Lakshmi-Intel Thank you for your response, I'll take a look. When loading a previously fine-tuned model, I run this (shortened for ease): `python run_classifier.py  --data_dir=$DATA_DIR --bert_config_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_config.json --vocab_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/vocab.txt --init_checkpoint=$DATA_DIR/saved_models/model.ckpt-500 --max_seq_length=256 --output_dir=$DATA_DIR/saved_models --do_eval=True --eval_batch_size=32 --use_tpu=True --tpu_name=node-1 --tpu_zone=us-central1-b --gcp_project=foobar`